# Fetch data for menu in next.js at build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I have built a layout component in next.js for a menu:

```
// layouts/menu.js

export default function Menu(props) {
    return (
        <nav className="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><Link href="#">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link href="#">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link href="#">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

The individual menu items should be fetched from an API during build time (with `getStaticProps`).

```
// layout/menu.js

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const data = await {placeholder: "placeholder"};

    return {
        props: {
            data
        }
    }
}
```

It is not possible to use the `getStaticProps` function in a component, so I have to fetch the data on the individual pages. However, I want to avoid writing the same function multiple times.

Is there a way to fetch the data for the menu items only once and then pass it to the layout component?

I already tried to execute the whole thing in `_app.js` and then pass it to the child component, but the `_app.js` file is not in the lifecycle, so this didn't work either.

Comment: You can write a separate function `fetchMyData` and just call that one inside `getStaticProps`.